# How can i transfer my steam games from Windows 10 to linux running under play on linux?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, wine, games, steam

I would just reinstall the games but currently I'm using data and am limited to 3 GBs of data which is nowhere near enough to download all of my games, so how can I copy the games from my Windows partition over to my Linux partition and have them work correctly (I have already setup steam within play on Linux and I have already mounted my windows partition). Also is it possible I can get both of them to use the same installation directory and so they can both use the same copy of the game (also so i don't need to copy/download a copy of the game onto each partition)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot - you will need to reinstall the games with the Linux version of the package. Both operating systems use different architecture, which is why not all games available in Windows are on Linux.

Comment: They plan to be running Steam games with POL, which still would be the Windows versions. Many games do perform suprisingly well when doing so but you are right in that they probably will have to re-install their games for that.